# How to prevent migration of data out of MDB?

Tags: ms-access, encryption, vb6, data-protection

I have a VB6/MDB product.

If I want to prevent a client from doing a mass transfer of data out of the MDB into another database, what can I do to the MDB?

The passwords on MDBs can be easily cracked so that is not an option.

Ideally it would be some sort of encryption that can only be decrypted by my product.  Are there any ready made solutions to achieve this?

EDIT: I have thought of just encrypting some important data fields, such customer names, ids which would render the database useless. However, this would only be for any data entered in the future.

Comment: Can you someone explain the downvote?  This is a perfectly legitimate question. It is the vendor's right to prevent unauthorised access to data.

Comment: Can you prove that MDB passwords can easily be cracked? And what method is used? If it's brute force then you just have to choose a good long password.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do question who owns the data.  When I use Salesforce, the software is theirs, but the *data* (addresses, contacts, projects, etc) is mine.

Comment: How tech savvy is the customer?  Can you keep the Access mdb encrypted at a file level and then your software can copy to a temp location, decrypt, and open exclusive in that temp location?  On close you would encrypt and copy back to the data folder.  Someone skilled could figure out how to get at it, but most people would not.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent a client from re-using their own data however they wish?

Comment: @HansUp: because I want to prevent them going to another product

Comment: @tcarvin: the customer owns the data but I don't think their rights over the data are diminished if they can only access the data with the existing product.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried by this question, then your best option is to upgrade your existing database to ACCDB format used in Access 2007/2010. Then Encrypt with a database password.

The new format uses the Windows Cryptographic API for database encryption. This change augments the level of sophistication required to decrypt the database via brute force attacks.
Moreover you could augment the default encryption key of 40bit following [this tutorial](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3752701/Secure-Microsoft-Access-Passwords-and-Encryption-in-Access-2007.htm)

Comment: How do you upgrade an MDB to an ACCDB?  And can you still use VB6 DAO to access the ACCDB?

Comment: To use the new format is necessary to install the ACE engine instead of the JET.OLEDB.4.0. [See here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734). To do the conversion process programmatically I think that you could still use the CompactDatabase method, but I have not tested